# Getting error while installing module

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am getting this error while installing new module. I have updated module list several time in order to resolve the issue. but no hope. here is the trace i am facing on my terminal.

```
2015-09-01 11:59:30,947 24953 ERROR software_001 openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 494, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 892, in convert_file
    fp = misc.file_open(pathname)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/tools/misc.py", line 199, in file_open
    return _fileopen(name, mode=mode, basedir=rtp, pathinfo=pathinfo, basename=basename)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/80/openerp/tools/misc.py", line 246, in _fileopen
    raise IOError('File not found: %s' % basename)
IOError: File not found: test_module/
```

I have checked each file, but no clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way of this kind of error is blank data in `__openerp__.py` file.

you should check `__openerp__.py` file. blank value in data list will cause this kind of error. remove `' '` or `" "` from data list.

```
{'name': 'Odoo Test',
 'version': '0.0.1',
 'category': 'Generic Modules/Others',
 'license': 'AGPL-3',
 'author': "atularvind",
 'website': 'http://www.atularvind.com/',
 'depends': [],
 'data': ['test_view.xml'],# [] instead of ["",]
 'demo': [],
 'installable': True,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're Not allowing to install Module just Because of Security reason, Your Module Operation Not Permitted...!!
So Need to do Just One Thing is Give File Permissions to Particular Module Using Chmod 777.
Go To root>> cd /home/odoo/addons/browseinfo/
Now Type Command==>>  chmod 777 -R browseinfo/

That'it, You sets the permission of a file/Folder...!!!
 Restart Your Server & Install/Upgrade Your Module...!!!

Comment: Thanks for  suggestions. I have checked everything seems well. issue is resolved by @atul's answer.